# Segmented Controller Setting Table Delegate and datasource at a segment ?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol

```
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            tblView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
            tblView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            tblView.register(UINib(nibName: "SegmentedAttachmentCell", bundle: Bundle.main ), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            iphoneCheck () // Iphone x Check
            initalSegmentSelected () // To Show First Index
        }

           func initalSegmentSelected () {
                self.segmentCtrl?.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
                screen = screenType.Media
                self.screenTypeData()
        }
   //MARK:- SegmentControllerUI
    func showTopSegmentControllerOnNavigationBar()
    {
        let appearance = SMSegmentAppearance()
        appearance.segmentOnSelectionColour = UIColor.DTColor()
        appearance.segmentOffSelectionColour = UIColor.clear
        appearance.titleOnSelectionFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        appearance.titleOffSelectionFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        appearance.titleOnSelectionColour = UIColor.white
        appearance.titleOffSelectionColour = UIColor.white
        appearance.contentVerticalMargin = 7.0
        segmentCtrl = SMSegmentView(frame: CGRect(x: 10.0, y: 4.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-20.0, height: 36.0), dividerColour: UIColor.DTColor(), dividerWidth: 3.0, segmentAppearance: appearance)
        segmentCtrl!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ChatAttachmentsViewController.selectSegmentInSegmentView(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        segmentCtrl!.addSegmentWithTitle(title: "Media", onSelectionImage: nil, offSelectionImage: nil,badgeCount: nil)
        segmentCtrl!.addSegmentWithTitle(title: "Files", onSelectionImage: nil, offSelectionImage: nil,badgeCount: nil)
        segmentCtrl!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.DTColor().cgColor
        segmentCtrl!.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        segmentCtrl!.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        segmentController.addSubview(segmentCtrl!)
        segmentController.backgroundColor = UIColor.LTColor()
    }
     // Setting Table
        func screenTypeData() {
            if screen == screenType.Media {
                tblView.isHidden = true
                self.tblView.isScrollEnabled = false
                attachmentsCollectionView.isHidden = false
                self.attachmentsCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
                self.attachmentsCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
            else if  screen == screenType.Document {
                tblView.dataSource = self
                tblView.delegate = self
                attachmentsCollectionView.isHidden = true
                self.attachmentsCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
                tblView.isHidden = false
                self.tblView.isScrollEnabled = true
                self.tblView.reloadData()
            }
        }
```

setting tableview datasource and delegate in screentypedata is it correct ? or should i set it on viewdidload (Problem encoutered it loads table also when clicked first time that causes lot of time so how to optimise it)

problem that i have doubts about :

- if setting in screentypedata whenever i tab the segmented control
  will it make a copy of datasource and delegate again and again ?
- how    to optimise the solution so that when i initally click only
  collection view reloads(Datsource and delegate works) not of
  tableview ?

Comment: Have you just this code ? Or other code is available related to this ? Can you post image to understand ?

Comment: just this code and my problem is i have used segmented control which have two table collection table and uitable and when i click button segmented controller loads .so i want only collection data loads as it is the one which is preselected and when user tab and other segment(Tableview) than only table data loads. @PaulMarshal

Comment: I think problem with your array's sorting. If you saying that, your data is double on every segment, then first check your segment change value method. I hope there are correct code.